# Was Hillary Clinton poisoned in 2016?

Tags: united-states, politics, hillary-clinton

In September 2016, there was claim that Hillary Clinton may have been poisoned during her election campaign.

[The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/early-lead/wp/2016/09/12/the-man-who-discovered-cte-thinks-hillary-clinton-may-have-been-poisoned/):

> Bennet Omalu […] suggests that Hillary Clinton’s campaign be checked for possible poisons after her collapse Sunday in New York.
>
> > *I must advice the Clinton campaign to perform toxicologic analysis of Ms. Clinton's blood. It is possible she is being poisoned.*
> >         — Bennet Omalu (@bennetomalu9168) [September 12, 2016](https://twitter.com/bennetomalu9168/status/775152373492776961)

The same claim was published at [The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/the-man-who-discovered-cte-thinks-hillary-clinton-may-have-been-poisoned-a7239711.html), [Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3788923/It-possible-Hillary-Clinton-POISONED-Putin-doctor-urges-Presidential-candidate-undergo-blood-tests-following-health-fears.html) and [Mirror](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/putin-poison-hilary-clinton-film-8834739).

I was trying to find out any following events — either debunking or confirming this rumor, e.g. she may performed some toxicological analysis, or made a public statement saying that this was fake news, or so.
To my surprise, I failed to find anything related after October 2016.

So my question is,
**Was the claimed posioning confirmed or refuted?**

Comment: The quote doesn't say she *was* poisoned, just that it was *possible* she was poisoned (which is trivially true).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Omalu later clarified to [Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2016/09/dr_bennet_omalu_suspects_hillary_clinton_was_poisoned_why.html) that he was not saying that Clinton was poisoned *by someone*:

> When he claimed the candidate might have been poisoned, he told me, he meant it in the sense that any drug can be poisonous—including prescription drugs and alcohol. “The media misconstrued it and sensationalized it to suggest or insinuate that Ms. Clinton was intentionally being poisoned by someone else,” Omalu said. As for the reference to Trump and Putin, he pointed out he’s “a student of literature” inclined to dabble in satire and hyperbole.

As to toxicological analysis, the Clinton campaign said that her stumble was related to [pneumonia](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/09/11/politics/hillary-clinton-health-2016-election/), so there is no reason for her to have an analysis:

> Many people inside the Clinton campaign did not know about the pneumonia diagnosis on Friday. An aide told CNN that Clinton "thought she could push through this ... she was feeling better" -- until Sunday morning, when she went to a September 11 memorial event in Manhattan but was forced to leave early.